# Upload video and stream video on laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

My app can already upload and save the video to public/files folder. my only problem is when im displaying (let's say a 1 minute long video) it doesn't play but when i play 2 seconds long video its working. i don't know why is this happening.

i have this is my controller

```
$input = Input::file('vid');
        $fileinput = $input->getClientOriginalName();
        $input = Input::file('vid')->move($destination,$fileinput);

        $post = New Post();
        $post->title = Input::get('title');
        $post->content = nl2br(Input::get('content'));
        $post->videos = $fileinput;
        $users->post()->save($post);
```

and in my views

```
<video width="600" height="500" controls>
<source src="{{ asset('img/'. $posts->videos)}}" type="video/mp4">
<source src="{{ asset('img/'. $posts->videos)}}" type="video/ogg">
<source src="{{ asset('img/'. $posts->videos)}}" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

i just want to understand why this is happening thanks

Comment: Can you play the 1 minute long video if you manually go into the uploads folder?

Comment: yeah i can play it perfectly. :/

Comment: What is the format of the video?

Comment: its mp4 sir,  what could be the problem to this?

Comment: when the video has a duration of more than 5 seconds it doesn't play, can i see your uploading method?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: still the same i cant play video..

Comment: ->getRealPath() is this necessary? or optional?

Comment: May be you should check your php.ini files and change their upload_max_filesize and post_max_size to higher values